# Communication between Client and RESTful web services

Tags: java, web-services, rest

I have a RESTful web Service that provide function of returning some data whenever a client send GET requests to ask for it:

```
    @GET
    @Path("/{deviceId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getDataResource(@PathParam("deviceId") long id){
        return dataService.getData(id);
    }
```

And the flow for this case would be the client sends request -> the web service returns value. But I want to ask that is it possible that the web service will automatically send response to the client when ever it has new data change inside of it? That means it not need to wait for the client to send request to ask for it. Because I would like to establish a communication between a client and some services running on an Application Server so that the client can always receives the newest data from the Application Server, so I think RESTful web Service can be a solution for it. And in oder to be ensure that the newest data will be transfered to the client side, so the server has to send to the client, not wait for the client to ask for it. Is RESTful web service provides any function like this?

Thank you all!

Comment: google this "push messages in REST services".

Answer (score 2):

> Is RESTful web service provides any function like this?

No. Not in the context you're asking for.

As answered before, the client could periodically poll for updates on the server. This is usually common option.

Another option - the original server posting updated on the "client". The client then becomes server itself. Viable, if you can expose services on the "client" side.

Maybe what are you looking for are **web sockets**. It is a long-lasting connection from client, where the server could keep returning data as they come.

There are some [books](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/developing-restful-services-jax-rs-20-websockets-and-json) around but you could search the net for more resources depending on the framework you use

Answer (score 0):

You can implement notification system(observer pattern), so that  client will poll the server in certain interval and any state change, it can get the result.

Answer (score -2):

You may use the Schedulers to push the data to the client in a certain intervals.